# Querys are taking long time found lock codes in error log?

Tags: mysql, sql, unix

when i am executing some querys for report purpose ,sometimes  those queries are taking 10 mins and some times same queries are taking hours of time and some times we are getting error like communication link failure.when i go through error log i found below error message ,how to fix it.

Error Message:

```
lock: 0x2b84f402e800:
lock: 0x2b84f401bb80:
lock: 0x2b84f401c410:
lock: 0x2b84f41d45f0:
lock: 0x2b84f41c1990:
lock: 0x22d657d0:
lock: 0x2308c650:
lock: 0x2b84f800d2c0:
lock: 0x22db4040:
lock: 0x22c0fa60:
lock: 0x22bc85a0:
lock: 0x22cf7710:

Key caches:
default
Buffer_size:     402653184
Block_size:           1024
Division_limit:        100
Age_limit:             300
blocks used:            19
not flushed:             0
w_requests:              1
writes:                  1
r_requests:            160
reads:                  19


handler status:
read_key:      8256766
read_next:   143651263
read_rnd         16764
read_first:      76853
write:         1941561
delete          306347
update:        1781864

Table status:
Opened tables:        149
Open tables:          142
Open files:            55
Open streams:           0

Alarm status:
Active alarms:   0
Max used alarms: 1
Next alarm time: 0
Memory status:
Non-mmapped space allocated from system: 368238592
Number of free chunks:                   168
Number of fastbin blocks:                0
Number of mmapped regions:               31
Space in mmapped regions:                761421824
Maximum total allocated space:           0
Space available in freed fastbin blocks: 0
Total allocated space:                   357157904
Total free space:                        11080688
Top-most, releasable space:              5359328
Estimated memory (with thread stack):    1132281856



Events status:
LLA = Last Locked At  LUA = Last Unlocked At
WOC = Waiting On Condition  DL = Data Locked

Event scheduler status:
State      : INITIALIZED
Thread id  : 0
LLA        : n/a:0
LUA        : n/a:0
WOC        : NO
Workers    : 0
Executed   : 0
Data locked: NO

Event queue status:
Element count   : 0
Data locked     : NO
Attempting lock : NO
LLA             : init_queue:139
LUA             : init_queue:149
WOC             : NO
Next activation : never
140328 17:17:08 [Warning] IP address 'xxxx' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
140328 17:20:00 [Warning] IP address 'xxxx' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
140328 17:29:43 [Warning] IP address 'xxxx' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
140331  9:55:47 [Warning] IP address 'xxxx' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
140331  9:56:09 [Warning] IP address 'xxxx' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
140331 11:38:35 [Warning] IP address 'xxxx' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
140331 15:07:04 [Warning] IP address 'xxxx' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are querying for report purposes, you shouldn't be locking any records. Ensure you are using `with (nolock)` in the query statements.

Comment: i am not using(nolock)